# NavigationDrawer toggle icon

Tags: android, navigation, icons, drawer

I use support libary to make a material like theme and I would like to change the drawer icon to the arrow when its opened.

I found some post here but I couldnt figure out the solution because I use the navigaton drawer sample by the android studio and I havent figured out everything

Comment: This is a sample like the Android Studio one but it uses material design. https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template

Comment: and can I use this for my 3.0 with Support libary? If yes, how ?:D its even more complecated I could run it if I copy the files to a project

Comment: This project has backward compatibility to api lvl 11. Which is Android 3.0 so yes you can used it. As for how to use it it depends on how far/coded your project is already. This is just a simple template. Like the one you get when you start a new Navigation drawer project on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generated the Navigation Drawer Activity with android studio, in the NavigationDrawerFragment class change the import

`android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`

to

`android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Yeah man thanks! works !!! I tried it once but i had some errors in the consturctor and could find the solution.but now I did. I had to make a toolbar " mToolbar = (Toolbar) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);" and then in the constructor replace the drawer drawable to mToolbar